# How to map JSON fields to custom object properties?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-web

I have a simple `json` message with some fields, and want to map it to a java object using `spring-web`.

Problem: my target classes fields are named differently than int he json response. How can I anyhow map them to the object without having to rename the fields in java?

Is there some annotation that could be placed here?

```
{
  "message":"ok"
}

public class JsonEntity {
    //how to map the "message" json to this property?
    private String value;
}

RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
rest.getForObject(url, JsonEntity.class);
```

Comment: `@JsonProperty` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To map a JSON property to a java object with a different name use  **[@JsonProperty annotation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html)**, and your code will be :

```
public class JsonEntity {
    @JsonProperty(value="message")
    private String value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@JsonProperty("message")
private String value;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you familiar it, you can also use Jaxb annotations to marshal/unmarshal json using Jackson

```
@XmlRootElement
public class JsonEntity {
   @XmlElement(name = "message")
  private String value;
}
```

But you must initialize your Jackson context propery. Here an example how to initialize Jackson context with Jaxb annotations.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
mapper.getDeserializationConfig().setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
mapper.getSerializationConfig().setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
```