# How @RequestMapping work in spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to find how `@RequestBody` is work

suppose i have post request with input json like this

```
{
"firstName" : "abcdf",
"email" : "abc@xyz.com",
"phoneNumber" :"0000000000"
}
```

but my java class have variable like

```
class Student{

private String fullName;
private String emailAddress;
private int mobileNumber;

// getter and setter here
}
```

my Rest End point is like.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveStudentInfo", method = RequestMethod.Post)
public setStudentInfo(@requestBody Student student){

return studentService.save(student);
}
```

***So What i do if my json veriable and java class variable is different is there any @annotation is there that i can use in Pojo class so it can map with different veriable name***

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29746495/3669624), you will find what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@JsonProperty("<json-name>")` annotation for it.

For e.g.

```
class Student {

    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    private String fullName;

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

}
```